# Calculate tangent of $f(x) = x^4 -2x^2 - x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given is the following function:

$f(x) = x^4 - 2x^2 - x$

**Question**

Give 2 points on the graph of this function that have the same tangent.

---

I am in a hurry and have no idea how to approach this, I've calculated the derivative $f'(x) = 4x^3 - 4x - 1$ but from this I don't know how to calculate the two points..

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Are you allowed to use graphic calculators? If yes, you can find the different values of x for which $f'(x)$ are the same...from there you can find the points.

Comment: Then you have to find the min and max of this function(using the derivative), and pick any two points between them.

Comment: @John: the question doesn't merely ask for two points with the same tangent _slope_ -- it asks for two points that share an actual tangent line.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oops, I misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=mx+n$ be the tangent, then you have
$$x^4-2x^2-x-(mx+n)=(x-k)^2(x-l)^2.$$
Then, you can compare the both sides. The answer will be $(k,f(k)),(l,f(l))$.

If my calculation is correct, I get $(k,l)=(1,-1),(-1,1)$. Please note that this is not $(k,f(k)),(l,f(l))$.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain why both sides are equal?

Comment: Just imagine the graph. The left hand side represents a graph which is tangent to $x$-axis at two points. Then, you'll understand why the right hand side is represented as above.

Comment: I got the following equations: $-2l-2k=0, l^2+4kl+k^2=-2, -2kl^2-2lk^2=-1-m, k^2l^2=-n$. Then, I get $k=-l, l^2=1, m=-1,n=-1$. I hope I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of blind calculation, it may be easiest to note that you can add any *first-degree* polynomial to the function without changing the $x$ coordinates of the points where the common tangent touches.

In particular, adding $x$ will leave $x^4-2x^2$ which is *even*, so its two *horizontal* tangents away from $x=0$ will necessarily coincide (and finding them is a simple matter of calculus; the derivative is $4x^3-4x$ whose roots are easily found).

Now that you have $x=\pm1$ at the tangent points, just plug that into your original function.

Comment: Nice+1. There is small error in the derivative; it should be changed to $4x^3-4x$

Comment: @John: Whoops, typo fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If the tangent of $y=f(x)$ at $a,b$ have the same slope, then:

$ f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)=f(b)+f'(b)(x-b) $

Answer (score 0):

Consider a general point on the curve. We have $x=p$ and $y=p^4-2p^2-p$. Moreover
$$\frac{\operatorname{d}\!y}{\operatorname{d}\!x} = 4p^3-4p-1 \, . $$
Hence, the equation of the tangent line at the point $x=p$ is given by
$$y=(4p^3-4p-1)x+(2-3p^2)p^2$$
To have the same tangent line at two different points, you need to find another point, say $x=q$, for which $4p^3-4p-1=4q^3-4q-1$  **and** $(2-3p^2)p^2 = (2-3q^2)q^2$.

The only solutions with $p \neq q$ are $(p,q)=(1,-1)$ and $(p,q)=(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

This question appeared in the 2016 FAMAT Calculus January Regional,

As the question does not assume $2$ distinct points of tangency, you could theoretically give the same two points. For example, $(0,0)$ and $(0,0)$ have the same tangent line, i.e. $y = -x$.